# VueJS Router History Mode on NGinx

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, nginx, vuejs2

I've been researching and i've found out many problems similar to my problem.

I have a docker-compose running on Digital Ocean with NGinx, VueJS and Static Landing Page.

It's all good until I've created a new route with a form. This route will be accessed by a link sent by email to the customers with an id to identify who is accessing the page.

**Structure example:**

https://example.org  -> landing page

https://example.org/quiz  -> my vuejs application

https://example.org/quiz/confirmation/some-customer-id  -> my router on vuejs

**VueJS Configuration:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: '8092',
    },
    publicPath: '/quiz/',
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: process.env.production ? '[name].[contenthash:8].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(), // so that file hashes don't change unexpectedly
        ],
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: 'single',
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                minSize: 0,
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name(module) {
                            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                            // or node_modules/packageName
                            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1]

                            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    lintOnSave: true,
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/app-custom.scss";
        `,
            },
        },
    },
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins.delete('prefetch')

    },
}
```

**VueJS Router Configuration:**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {Trans} from '@/plugins/translation'
import {ROUTER_NAME} from "./names";


const Quiz = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Quiz" */ '@/views/Quiz.vue')
const QuizResults = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "QuizResults" */ '@/views/QuizResults.vue')
const QuizSuccess = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "QuizSuccess" */ '@/views/QuizSuccess.vue')
const QuizConfirmation = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "QuizResults" */ '@/views/QuizConfirmation.vue')
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/:lang',
        component: {
            template: '<router-view></router-view>',
        },
        beforeEnter: Trans.routeMiddleware,
        children: [
            {

                path: '/',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ,
                component: Quiz
            }, {
                path: '/results',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_RESULTS,
                component: QuizResults
            }, {
                path: '/success',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_SUCCESS,
                component: QuizSuccess
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/confirmation/:quizId',
        name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_CONFIRMATION,
        component: QuizConfirmation,
        props: true
    },
    {
        // Redirect user to supported lang version.
        path: '*',
        redirect(to) {
            return Trans.defaultLanguage
        }
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/quiz/',
    routes
})

export default router
```

**NGinx configuration:**

```
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        location /quiz {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        location /shop {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.org/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /quiz {
            alias /var/www/html/quiz;
            expires -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /quiz/index.html;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

}
```

I have followed all available documentation and stackoverflow questions but all of them aren't working.

Basically, when I click on the link *https://example.org/quiz/confirmation/some-customer-id* the site is redirect to `/quiz/index.html` defined on `location /quiz` configuration:

```
location /quiz {
            alias /var/www/html/quiz;
            expires -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /quiz/index.html;
        }
```

Do you know what can I do to solve this issue? If you need any more information, let me know.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the slash '/' in the path of the children when using nested routes,

so your vue-router config will be something like this:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/:lang',
        component: {
            template: '<router-view></router-view>',
        },
        beforeEnter: Trans.routeMiddleware,
        children: [
            {

                path: '',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ,
                component: Quiz
            }, {
                path: 'results',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_RESULTS,
                component: QuizResults
            }, {
                path: 'success',
                name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_SUCCESS,
                component: QuizSuccess
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/confirmation/:quizId',
        name: ROUTER_NAME.QUIZ_CONFIRMATION,
        component: QuizConfirmation,
        props: true
    },
    {
        // Redirect user to supported lang version.
        path: '*',
        redirect(to) {
            return Trans.defaultLanguage
        }
    }
]
```

you can check the vue-router docs [Here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).